# Use comma to create a new tag on #react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

On version *1.3.0* every time the user presses the key "," react-select creates a new tag, this is useful because before implementing this library we have cases were users introduce tags as a single string instead of multiple by pressing enter.

Unfortunately, I can not find any way to do this after the refactor of *2.0* is there any way to configure this behaviour?

- [Example on version 1.3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWwaX.gif)
- [Example on lastest version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbIdh.gif)

Comment: Please add more details. At the very least questions should include a minimal example of the code as well as what you have currently tried.

Comment: I'm not sure if the code example will be relevant, what I'm asking is, if it's possible since I can not find anything on the docs or in others implementations of react-select with this version. Also while creating a new issue in the repository, they encourage to make questions on StackOverflow when is not directly a code issue.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to custom a bit `react-select` in order to achieve what you want.

Basically this is what I ended up with:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import CreatableSelect from "react-select/lib/Creatable";

type State = {
  options: [{ [string]: string }],
  value: string | void
};

const createOption = (label: string) => ({
  label,
  value: label.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, "")
});

const defaultOptions = [
  createOption("One"),
  createOption("Two"),
  createOption("Three")
];

export default class CreatableAdvanced extends Component<*, State> {
  state = {
    inputValue: "",
    options: defaultOptions,
    value: []
  };
  onKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 188) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (this.state.inputValue !== "") {
        this.handleCreate(this.selectRef.state.inputValue.slice(0, -1));
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({ inputValue: this.state.inputValue + e.key });
    }
  };
  handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    this.setState({ value: newValue });
  };
  handleCreate = (inputValue: any) => {
    const { options, value } = this.state;
    const newOption = createOption(inputValue);
    this.setState({
      inputValue: "",
      options: [...options, newOption],
      value: [...value, newOption]
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { isLoading, options, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        ref={r => (this.selectRef = r)}
        isClearable
        isMulti
        isDisabled={isLoading}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onCreateOption={this.handleCreate}
        options={options}
        value={value}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/74801436q6) of what you want.

The idea is to bypass the native `inputValue` of the select and pass your own one. With `onKeyDown` function you can either decide to fill the `inputValue` or create a new tag.

Comment: Your solution works to create tags using a comma, but I need to completely replicate the beheiviour of an input, for example, using *backspace* or any of the special keys like **enter**, **ctrl**, **alt**, **supr**... will print the name of the key, is there any way to fix this easily? I'm trying to conditionally handle them but it seems like a complex solution.

Comment: @DanielDoblado ok it’s not really explain in your question I’ll try to update my code to do what you want but I’ll need an example of what you’re talking about for the special keys

Comment: "_I’ll need an example of what you’re talking about for the special keys_"  you can see what I mean with your live example https://codesandbox.io/s/74801436q6, if you try to use keys like backspace, Alt or Ctrl https://i.imgur.com/p0AlwCn.png , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `isMulti`, you can make a comma trigger a new value like with the `onInputChange` prop:

```
isMulti
onInputChange={(value, { action }) => {
  if (action === 'input-change') {
    const lastChar = value[value.length - 1]
    if (lastChar === ',') {
      const valueToAdd = value.slice(0, -1)
      // call your own state handler here
      onChange([...current, valueToAdd])

      // return the new text for the input
      return ''
    }
  }
}}
```